How to implement Authentication for Azure Function - Google provider - Static WebApp - unauthorized
I have a static web app that has google authentication Login and it works.
I have azure function - the out of the box - HttpExample.
The azure function works when accessed without Authentication.
In GCP client/oauth configuration
Authorised JavaScript origins
http://localhost:3000
https://i***.5.azurestaticapps.net
https://l***ons.azurewebsites.net

Authorised redirect URIs
http://localhost:3000
https://i***.5.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/google/callback
https://l***ons.azurewebsites.net

Using the link - configure provider I configured provider in Azure functions
My configuration

I am not sure of redirect urls to be used.
Problem:
Testing via postman - "Get" request for azure function, using Bearer Token and pasted token obtained using static web app.
Error: 410 Unauthorized
Doubts:

I am not sure if the GCO redirect url should be of form....login/oauth2/code/google
Hope my configuration in Authentication section of azure functions is correct

How to solve this issue? Is there a setup issue?
(also how to debug/trace)
Edit 2:
Code + Test inside Azure functions with Authorization header ( with token from postman)
Error:
Security issue: Request to send auth token to untrusted domain 'blah.azurewebsites.net'. Only a fixed set of domains should be configured to receive auth tokens. Command name: 
Edit:
My example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/training/modules/develop-azure-functions-app-with-maven-plugin/6-deploy-function-azure
A csharp example: (not sure how to translate / replicate in java)
https://github.com/stuartleeks/AzureFunctionsEasyAuth/
Edit 3:
Postman config to generate token


What is the version of your Function App?

I deployed from maven, 
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION
~4
. I see runtime version - 4.1036.3.3. So I presume it is 4. I also see this         <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.24.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
<azure.functions.java.library.version>2.2.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>

@Harshitha do you work in microsoft? you were very specific about version, is there any known issue with version ?

Checking the version to repro the issue from my end.

ok. Goal is to make my function secure using Function App Authentication and be able to test using postman or function app code + test with authorization header and getting response instead of unauthorized

I have followed below steps to access the function App secured with Authentication.
Create a function app and add the identity provider in Authentication.

It creates a new Entra ID application (highlighted below).


Navigate to the Entra ID application created above, open API permissions, add a permission=>My APIs=> select the API and add   user_impersonation permission.

Open Expose API, you can see the exposed API as below.

Redirect URLs added in Application=> Authentication


Note the scope for further use to access function app.

Go to overview, note Client_ID, Tenant ID and client secret available in the Certificates & Secrets.
Generate new access token using the credentials:
GET https://functionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1

Grant_Type : Authorization Code
Auth URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Access Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
Callback URL : <RedirectURL>
ClientID : <ClientID>
Client Secret : <Client_secret>
Scope : api://xxx/user_impersonation


Click on Generate Token to generate access token and the token will be saved then you will be able to run the function.

Able to access the authenticated function app and run the function successfully.


Please can you do the same with google authentication? or github? My screens are different from yours. Cant see "Expose an API" option. I presume "It creates a new Entra ID application" means an identity provider, which is google in my case. Is user_impersonation required? I am adding scopes :email profile openid. I can't do all the above steps , as my account is student account. Also please answer with constraints mentioned in the question - please add google and show how you are appending authorization in header - access token or the big id_token from postman ?

You can refer this article. I have implemented authentication using GitHub. I have generated access token and saved automatically to use it further to access function, refer Image1 & Image2.

ok. How about google? the link does mention google in the table - App service google login. I don't have access to  Azure AD B2C tenant. How to debug? Getting simple things done on Azure is horrible. I can't convince people to use github instead of google. So may be I cant switch to github,

If you enable authentication and authorization in your linked Functions app, it must use Azure App Service Authentication and authorization provider version 2. How to check this please

Did you check this MSDOC?

can you start a chat please? I tried different options - 1. Authentication in function app...NOT WORKING. 2.API Management route...but not sure if my API is secure or not, also I need update a lot...so stopped that. 3. APIs in static web app, this looks securing - Azure Static Web Apps (Linked) function app. This is not working axios error. How to test using Code + Test in function app after Google identity provider?

Scenario: If static web app and function app are linked, how to test function app api from "Code + Test" >> Test/Run ? How do you acquire token and use it ?

There is a doc similar to your requirement but using Microsoft Identity provider. Check if it helps.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

if google configuration is not done, how can you confirm if there is a known issue? I have seen some references similar to the issue, but that forum is only for contributors. Simple scenario: Create a function app that required auth header, add google as identity provider, test using code + test supplying an access token generated using google oauth playground. makes sense?
